# How can I get SnailSvn to run a custom diff command?

Tags: bash, subversion

How can I make SnailSvn use vimdiff or any custom diff script? It only has a predefined list of options.

To setup its diff support (for opendiff aka FileMerge), it asks you to copy the following script to:
`~/Library/Application Scripts/net.langui.SnailSVN.DiffTool/difftool.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
pkill -nf ScriptMonitor
sh "$@"
```

The argument is a generated diff-cmd.sh file that looks something like this:

```
#/bin/bash
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/opendiff" "/var/folders/nn/000000000000000000000000000000/T/net.langui.SnailSVNFree//r422640 Code.cs" "/Users/idbrii/code/game/Assets/Standard Assets/Unlit/Planes/Code.cs"
```

I tried to replace it with something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=$(grep opendiff "$@" | cut -d\  -f2-)
echo mvimdiff $args >> ~/snailsvndifftool.log 2>&1
```

But instead I get too many files -- despite files containing quotes, they're still split up by spaces.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2005201/79125), I found `eval`:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=$(grep opendiff "$@" | sed -e 's,"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/opendiff",/usr/local/bin/mvimdiff,')
echo diff: $args >> ~/snailsvndifftool.log 2>&1
# What's this shady thing?
eval       $args >> ~/snailsvndifftool.log 2>&1
```

However, doing `eval` on arbitrary arguments seems unnecessarily insecure and I couldn't get [arrays to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12137030/79125) (i.e., `mvimdiff ${args[@]}`), so instead I force mvimdiff to be at the beginning of the line and only allow a set of characters:

```
#!/bin/bash

args=$(grep opendiff "$@" | sed -E 's,"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/opendiff",,; s/[^A-Za-z0-9.~/"_ -]//g; s,^,/usr/local/bin/mvimdiff,')
echo diff: $args >> ~/snailsvndifftool.log 2>&1
eval $args >> ~/snailsvndifftool.log 2>&1
```

There's probably something I'm missing, so I hope someone has a better answer.